# Jquery plugin - onclick event for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, onclick

I'm creating a jQuery plugin that listens to click events on multiple elements that have the same ID name.

```
// On click listener
base.$el.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

The click event works only on the first of multiple HTML elements.

**How I'm initializing the plugin:**

```
$('#test-button').scrollTo();
```

How can I make the click event work on all elements with selector `#test-button`?

**JS Fiddle (simplified):**

https://jsfiddle.net/8ujeqwey/2/

Notice how the alert shows only when you click button one. It should work on all buttons.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: `$(this)` inside handler function represents the actual element

Comment: @ArunPJohny Wow i didn't know it would effect JS!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8ujeqwey/4/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id - *There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID` *must* be unique on each document context., use `classes` instead,

```
<a href="#" class="test">One</a>
<a href="#" class="test">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="test">Three</a>

$('.test').scrollTo();
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/8ujeqwey/3/)

Answer (score 1):

ID's are used in a unique way. Just use a class instead and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, IDs must be unique within a scope. If the design of your plugin is to harvest multiple elements with a specific ID, you could do it if the elements with the desired ID were scoped (although technically invalid HTML markup, it still works):

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" id="test">One</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" id="test">Two</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" id="test">Three</a>
</div>

$('.content #test').scrollTo();
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y9smmmpe/1/

But you should use a class if possible, that's the way to select multiple elements.

Comment: This is a workaround but still it's invalid HTML markup. BTW, a better workaround would be to use attribute selector `[id=test]`. Anyway, using valid HTML markup is the best way, as you suggest it (using class instead)

Comment: True - I've added a bit to note this :). The attr selector is better in this case I agree.

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s must be unique, you must never have more than one element with the same `ID`.

Use a `class` instead:

```
<a href="#" class="test">One</a>
<a href="#" class="test">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="test">Three</a>
```

And the JQ:
`$('.test').scrollTo();`

And css:
`.test{/*your css here*/ }`

Though, according to your question specifically, it seems you're trying to create a plugin that is already a core functionality of JQ:

To listen to click event on multiple elements, you just do:

`$('.elementClassHere').on('click', function(){
 //your function here..
});`